# How does the command "make menuconfig" uses ncurses library?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ncurses

I want to know how the configuration command "make menuconfig" to make use of ncurses library?

Does it mean the binary of make is linked with ncurses so file? If so, we can't use make command when we don't have ncurses library.

What's the whole picture here, about make menuconfig using ncurses library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs a program, `scripts/kconfig/mconf` which is written in `C`.

I don't think it is compiled on the fly (as @tangrs suggests) since the objects and executables in my directory are months before my last use of it.

Comment: I have checked kernel source code. scripts/kconfig/Makefile tells that if we choose target menuconfig, then mconf will be compiled.

Comment: @Daniel:  that makes sense the first time it is run when it probably doesn't exist.  But I don't think it is rebuilt just to run it again.

Comment: @ wallyk: Try make clean, then make menuconfig. see the log, it begins to compile. But I'm checking where's the entry point in kernel Makefile.

Comment: @ wallyk: OK, I have got it. Entry point is accessed by this line from Makefile "%config: scripts_basic outputmakefile FORCE". Great, mconf uses ncurses lib. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `make menuconfig` compiles a program that is linked to the ncurses library and then runs it.